# How do I switch phones while on a Google Voice call?

Tags: google-voice

If I initiate a Google Voice call from one phone and want to switch midway through the call to another phone, how can I do it?

I heard there was some button combination I could press to make all my other phones ring while I'm on a call.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no way of switching phones for a call you initiate. Per [this](http://www.google.com/support/voice/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=115080) Google Voice Help article:

> Keep in mind that it's not possible to switch phones during calls you make through your Google number

You can switch phones for a call your receive though

> To switch phones in the middle of an incoming call, just press * while you're talking, and your other phones will ring

Answer (score 2):

For *incoming* calls [you can press `*` to switch the call to another one of your phones](http://www.google.com/support/voice/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=115080).  However this capability is not currently available for outgoing calls.

I don't know if this is the reason, but a lot of people call into automated systems that require entering something on the keypad.  So if Google Voice intercepted things like `*` for switching phones and `4` for call recording as they do on incoming calls, it would probably cause more trouble that it would solve.  Perhaps in the future they might allow initiating the switch via a web interface or smartphone app.

Comment: That makes sense. I hadn't thought of that. thanks.